# MBAM1 Sonoma: homebrew update bricked all browsers - how to recover?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, upgrade, apple-silicon

I am in quite a bit of hell right now.

For ages I have not upgraded brave because for some reason it could not do it automatically. I always assumed this was due to macOS being wholly useless when it comes to *multiple independent user accounts*, which is how I use all my OSes: account A for stuff A, account B for stuff B etc. Helps me cope with stress and prevent distractions.

Now, this morning I felt that it is high time to do an update.

So I switched back to the main account and executed

```
brew upgrade
brew upgrade brave-browser
```

Since then

1. all browsers on all accounts do not have internet access anymore (except Safari) - Firefox, Chrome
2. the original Brave install says "this application is not supported on this Mac"

I asked lolGPT for advice. It suggested to rollback as home-brew, according to console output, created a backup. Well, it didn't. Backup folder as claimed by console doesn't exist.

Here is the console output from that whole episode:

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
brave-browser 1.39.111.0,139.111 -> 1.62.165.0
==> Upgrading brave-browser
==> Downloading https://updates-cdn.bravesoftware.com/sparkle/Brave-Browser/stab
######################################################################### 100.0%
==> Backing App 'Brave Browser.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/brave-browser/1.3
==> Removing App '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'
==> Moving App 'Brave Browser.app' to '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
==> Purging files for version 1.62.165.0 of Cask brave-browser
==> Purging files for version 1.62.165.0 of Cask brave-browser
Warning: Reverting upgrade for Cask brave-browser
==> Purging files for version 1.39.111.0,139.111 of Cask brave-browser
Error: brave-browser: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'.
```

I don't care *right now* for "Why TF does homebrew purge the backup?".

I care how I can

- get list of open tabs
- storage from extensions installed (I always use session buddy to back up sessions every 60s because computers suck at reliablility)

### Any ideas that lolGPT doesn't have?

Comment: The general browser issues seem unrelated to the Brave install. What was the output of `brew upgrade`?

Comment: Also, you need to fix the xcrun error. Did you migrate your Homebrew install from an Intel to an ARM Mac?

Comment: @nohillside The ```upgrade``` output is in the OP. The ```update``` output follows: https://pastebin.com/XAkdnWuy

Comment: @nohillside no, I have not used macOS before getting the M1 Air.

Comment: I actually don't understand why xcrun is relevant in the brew workflow. I do not recall doing anything that might impact it, except maybe installs of python or other DEs via homebrew.

Comment: If this is a fresh install, I wonder why it installs to /usr/local, should be /opt/homebrew. xcrun is required to compile stuff.

Comment: Are you in mainland China? or running this from behind a firewall?

Comment: Also, is Brave the only thing installed with Homebrew?

Comment: I am in Germany, do not use firewalls (because in contrast to Linux or even Windows, there isn't really anything like that on macOS [or I am an ignorant mutton but I wanted to have a YouTube loopback to 127.0.0.1 but it can't be done])

I installed lots of things with homebrew. Brave certainly was one of the first

Comment: I dug around and formally speaking, homebrew SHOULD be installed in /opt/homebrew

I do not know why this isn't the case. Does terminal history on a Mac reach back all the way or does it get pruned?

Comment: History gets pruned. And yes, /opt should be the place. It probably makes sense to start over.